# Enrich mongodb aggregate with lookup table

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is a bit esoteric, but I'm trying use MongoDB aggregation to rollup some data, where not all the data I need is contained in the original source collection.  For example in the source data I have a contractKey, but in the target I need the contract to be an Object containing the key, an id, and a name.  I can find the other elements I need from another database and can easily build Javascript objects in advance containing arrays of the results mapped to keys, like this contracts object:

```
{
    "8c22ed35-0223-11e8-9e8f-d8257c2a48a1:1131" : {
        "contract" : {
            "name" : "2f3725fa-0e4d-4a0d-acc0-59c1cce0f502.demo-Sandbox-anonymous",
            "id" : 1131,
            "key" : "8c22ed35-0223-11e8-9e8f-d8257c2a48a1:1131"
        }
    },
    "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001" : {
        "contract" : {
            "name" : "Default Contract for Policy Manager Services",
            "id" : 1001,
            "key" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001"
        }
    }
}
```

Where I'm struggling is how to access these arrays within the aggregate function.  I am running aggregate from the mongo shell and have a script that includes the code that generates these arrays at the start.  Once I get to the aggregate I'm trying this:

```
db.AUDIT.aggregate([ 
    {
        $match : {
            containerKey: "3cfe0914-3ef3-4135-9795-4b8cb7d8" // Just here to only get data from my ND while testing
        }
    }, 
    {
        $group : {
            _id : { // This will aggregate by 7 different elements starting with the time slice
                timestamp: { $dateToString: // Convert the ISO Date to the internal format we use
                    {
                        format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%LZ",
                        date: { $subtract : [ "$requestDtsCal", { // The start date of each block
                            $mod : [ { // The remainder
                                $subtract : [ "$requestDtsCal", baseDate ] // The offset
                                }, divisor ] // The interval
                            } ]
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                serviceKey: "$serviceKey",
                operationuuid: "$operationuuid",
                contractKey: "$contractKey",
                bindingTemplateKey: "$bindingTemplateKey",
                containerKey: "$containerKey",
                status: { $or: [ "$isSoapFaultByMP", "$isSoapFaultByNextHop" ]} // Set a status variable in the id based on if there is any fault
            },
            // For each group, we determine which elements we want to pass to the next stage of the lifecycle
            _count: {$sum: 1}, // Could all the documents matched
            // For each of these section this data will be the same for all records as these are all part of the aggregation group
            // use the $first operator to just take the value of the elements from the first document in the group
            contract : contracts["$contractKey"],
            container: {$first: { name: "$containerName", id: "$containerId", key: "$containerKey"}},  // Build the container object
.....
```

Note the `contract : contracts["$contractKey"],` when I try and run this I get the error:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "the group aggregate field 'contract' must be defined as an expression inside an object",
    "code" : 15951
} : aggregate failed
```

So either I have some syntax wrong or I'm trying to do something I just can't do.  Any ideas?

Update:

I realized I needed to turn that into an expression, so I changed it to:

```
contract : {$first: contracts["$contractKey"]},
```

That doesn't fail, but it is not finding the object in the table, so I'm ending up with an undefined contract object in the result.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a76463a47f407556afc9192"),
    "_count" : 180.0,
    "contract" : undefined,
    "container" : {
        "key" : "acb7eb7f-b28e-4ead-944f-ed116d61"
    },
    "service" : {
        "name" : "Metadata Exchange Service",
        "id" : 20052,
        "key" : "uddi:soa.com:ws-mex-servicekey"
    },
    "organization" : {
        "name" : null,
        "id" : 1000,
        "key" : "uddi:soa.com:managementconfigurationbusinesskey"
    },
    "operation" : {
        "name" : "GetMetadata",
        "id" : 2628,
        "key" : "e10a535e-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7"
    },
    "binding" : {
        "id" : 2514,
        "key" : "uddi:d6e13584-7655-11e6-8911-aed52c780d1b"
    },
    "timestamp" : "2018-02-03 22:00:00.000Z",
    "contractKey" : "d36ac6d6-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7:1001",
    "containerKey" : "acb7eb7f-b28e-4ead-944f-ed116d61",
    "serviceKey" : "uddi:soa.com:ws-mex-servicekey",
    "organizationKey" : "uddi:soa.com:managementconfigurationbusinesskey",
    "bindingKey" : "uddi:d6e13584-7655-11e6-8911-aed52c780d1b",
    "operationKey" : "e10a535e-7473-11e6-8466-ba5d36e9bcc7",
    "response" : {
        "size" : {
            "sum" : 61200
        },
        "time" : {
            "min" : 3,
            "max" : 6,
            "avg" : 4.33333333333333,
            "sum" : 780
        }
    },
    "request" : {
        "qosviolation" : {
            "sum" : 0
        },
        "size" : {
            "min" : 335,
            "max" : 346,
            "sum" : 61200
        },
        "count" : {
            "sum" : 180.0
        },
        "status" : "Success"
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: I edited this to show an update - still not quite there, but some progress.

Comment: Is `contracts` separate collection or a variable in scope?

Comment: It's a variable set before running the aggregate.  It seems to be in scope, because having moved this to the project pipeline (which I think it belongs), I can try this:  contract : {$cond: {if: {$ne: [contracts["$_id.contractKey"], null]},  then: "true", else: "false"}} and it outputs true, but if I try and replace true with contracts["$_id.contractKey"] then the output shows contract: undefined.

Comment: all these type of assignments are translated to hard-coded variables in aggregation pipeline before starting pipeline, that's why you see undefined

Comment: Ok - so is there any way I can do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: one way is to keep contracts in separate collection and do `$lookup`

Comment: @Saravana - thanks for the suggestion.  I rebuilt the aggregate using lookup - it works well.  Performance is a bit of a struggle with the amount of data I'm pushing.  If you want to turn your suggestion into a quick answer I can accept it.